# Javascript string split with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a string using a regular expression for links (urls).

The regex in question is

```
var regex = new RegExp('(?:^(?:(?:[a-z]+:)?//)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:localhost|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$)')
```

If i do

```
regex.test("https://google.com"); // returns true
```

but doing -

```
"Go to https://google.com".split(regex); 
// return ["Go to https://google.com"]
```

Whereas i expect it to return

```
["Go to ", "https://google.com"]
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Your missing escapes for the \S \u

Comment: I don't get it. How is it able to match "https://google.com"?

Comment: Luck, \S+ is S+ for example which does not fail the regexp but is not checking what you think.  You should probably state the pattern your trying to match.

Comment: Why do you need such a complex regex to match a URL?

Comment: Your pattern does not accept for anything except continuous characters (a-z)  then :// ... in the beginning, so it's not going to match the second example obviously.

Comment: @anubhava would appreciate simpler regex to do the same. I picked this one from https://github.com/kevva/url-regex

Comment: @AlexK. The patterns i am trying to match might have protocols as http or https, might have a subdomain (watch.apple.com), and have a path component which can then have a hash in it (https://watch.apple.com/go#/newone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're using a string literal to build your regex, which means that you have to escape your backslashes (since a backslash has a special meaning in strings, used for the line feed char `\n` for example):

```js
var regex = new RegExp('(?:^(?:(?:[a-z]+:)?//)(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:localhost|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,})))(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\\S*)?$)');
```

Another solution would be to use the regex literal, as JavaScript proposes one, but you would then have to escape the slashes:

```js
var regex = /(?:^(?:(?:[a-z]+:)?\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:localhost|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[\/?#]\S*)?$)/;
```

---

Then, your regex will try to match against the entire input due to the [`^` and `$` anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). So if you remove them (or better, replace them with [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`), you'll be able to find URLs in a string for example:

```js
var regex = /(?:\b(?:(?:[a-z]+:)?\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:localhost|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[\/?#]\S*)?\b)/;
```

---

But, the main point is that you're misunderstanding the `split` concept. Given the string `"hello world"`, if you split by space, you'll end up with `["hello", "world"]`: no more space anymore since it was the char that was used to split.

That is, if you split by the URL regex, the output array won't contain the URLs anymore. It seems to me that a lookahead could suit your needs:

```js
var regex = /(?=(?:\b(?:(?:[a-z]+:)?\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:localhost|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[\/?#]\S*)?\b))/;
"Go to https://google.com".split(regex) // ["Go to ", "https://google.com"]
```

The regex explained:

```
(?=(?:\b(?:(?:[a-z]+:)?//)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:localhost|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?\b))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qsM8C8rXfpowKjFz)

By splitting a string with a positive lookahead `(?=content_of_lookahead)`, you'll split by each *interchar* that is followed by the content of the lookahead.

Comment: I didn't understand a lot of it but it works! Will try to read about lookaheads. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[8 Regular Expressions You Should Know](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149)**.

To match an url you can use following regex :

```
var regex = "(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w# \.-]*)*\/?$";

"Go to https://google.com".split(regex); 
// return ["https://google.com"]
```

**[Live example](https://regex101.com/r/uE9bE7/3)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @MukeshSoni just updated my answer work now for `google.com/#my/regex";`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. for your intervention, i'm not sure what you mean by _unescaped \_ why url will contain `\\`.